# Login em MYSQL em C#

Tags: c#, mysql

Sou iniciante em C#,estou tentado validar um usuário num formulário de login, porém o meu código não compara o resultado da SQL, permitindo o acesso do programa sem o ter o usuário e senha registrado no banco.
Como posso fazer essa validação?
Segue o código abaixo.

```
class Validacao:Pessoas
{
    public void Login()
    {
        Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
        Conexao.Conectar();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
            //Comando SQL
            comando.CommandText = "select count(*)from `pessoas` where `Usuario` = '@Usuario' and `Senha` = '@Senha'";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Usuario);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", Senha);
            //Conectar com o banco
            comando.Connection = Conexao.Conectar();
            //Executar Comando
            bool resultado = comando.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
            if (resultado == true)
            { 
               Principal principal = new Principal();
               principal.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha inválidos", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro do Banco de dados " + er, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            Conexao.Desconectar();
            Conexao.Limpar();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Desde já agradeço a ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

O comando que você executou é um count(*), se você precisar dos dados do usuário na aplicação o correto seria:

```
select * from pessoas where Usuario = @Usuario and Senha = @Senha
```

Porquê assim você recuperaria os dados do usuário para utilizar na aplicação.

O problema da aplicação estar sempre entrando mesmo com o login e senha incorreto se deve ao fato que o comando que você está executando:

```
bool resultado = comando.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
```

esse comando sempre retorna true porquê ele espera um resultado ou um valor nulo, o correto seria utilizar o comando ExecuteScalar.

Segue abaixo código corrigido:

```
class Validacao:Pessoas
{
    public void Login()
    {
        Conexao conexao = new Conexao();
        Conexao.Conectar();
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand comando = new MySqlCommand();
            //Comando SQL
            comando.CommandText = "select * from `pessoas` where `Usuario` = '@Usuario' and `Senha` = '@Senha'";
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usuario", Usuario);
            comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Senha", Senha);
            //Conectar com o banco
            comando.Connection = Conexao.Conectar();
            //Executar Comando
            var resultado = comando.ExecuteScalar();

            if (resultado != null)
            { 
               Principal principal = new Principal();
               principal.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Usuário ou Senha inválidos", "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
        catch (MySqlException er)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Erro do Banco de dados " + er, "Aviso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            Conexao.Desconectar();
            Conexao.Limpar();
        }
    }
}
```